# How to install the new JetBrains code editor Fleet?

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

I just seen that Fleet, the new JetBrains code editor is available on JetBrains Toolbox. But in mine, I am not able to see it. I tried to search for update, maybe I'll see it in the list but nothing happens.

So I want to know if someone is able to see in JetBrains Toolbox or already install it. If so, please help me to install also. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: It's in a **Closed Preview** stage and should be to early to "anyone can try". https://www.jetbrains.com/fleet/

Comment: it's not available for Linux yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not available yet. You can subscribe to be notified when the open preview is available.

Comment: This is now no longer correct.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains Fleet is now in EAP (Early Access Preview). You can install it through JetBrains Toolbox.

https://www.jetbrains.com/fleet/
https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/